# How to set image field as optional?

Tags: django, django-templates

How to set image field as optional? I am trying to set image field as optional(None or selected). Image field is None its throwing "MultiValueDictKeyError" when submit the form. I want to make this image field as None.
models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid:
          first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
          last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
          image = request.FILES['images']
          file_storage = FileSystemStorage()
          obj = Profile(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, image=file_storage.save(image.name, image))
          return render(request, 'index.html',{})
       return render(request, 'index.html',{})
    return render(request, 'index.html',{})
```

index.html

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control form-control" id="fname">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control form-control" id="lname">
      <input type="file" name="images" class="form-control" id="image">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5 mb-5">Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the same method you're using in the other fields:

```
image = request.FILES.get('images')
```

this will make image = None if it doesn't exist in the request. then:

```
image_saved = None
if image is not None:
  image_saved = FileSystemStorage().save(image.name, image)
obj = Profile(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, image=image_saved)
```