# Facing ErrorDetail(string='The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid') -Django Rest + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have an Edit Profile page where a user can edit the previously entered information. The form also contains an image field. I fetch the data from the backend and prefill the fields with the existing data. Now the data that comes for the image is basically the path to the media folder where the image gets stored once uploaded. Now suppose the user does not want to change the previously entered image and submits the form I get the below error

```py
{'profile_photo': [ErrorDetail(string='The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')]}
```

Please suggest to me what should I do to control this error if an image file is not received in the request.data

Below are the codes

**views.py**

```py
api_view(['PUT'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
@parser_classes([MultiPartParser, FormParser])     
def edit_teacher_detail(request):
  
   data = request.data
   
   if data is not None:
     
     id = data.get('id')
     
     queryset = TeacherDetail.objects.get(id = id)
     
     serializer = TeacherDetailSerializer(instance=queryset, data = data)
     
     try:
       if serializer.is_valid():
         serializer.save()
         return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
         print(f'\nThis is the error in the serialization {serializer._errors}\n')
         return Response({'message': serializer._errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
     except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       return Response(status=500)
```

**reactjs API sending the data**

```js
export const editTeacherDetail = async (detailsData, photo) => {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("id", detailsData.id);
  formData.append("is_verified", true);
  formData.append("name", detailsData.name.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("adhaar_number", detailsData.adhaar_number);
  formData.append("phone", detailsData.phone);
  formData.append("location", detailsData.location.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("full_address", detailsData.full_address.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("age", detailsData.age);
  formData.append("gender", detailsData.gender.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("name_of_school", detailsData.name_of_school.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("experience", detailsData.experience);
  formData.append("teach_for_no_days", detailsData.teach_for_no_days);
  formData.append("subject", detailsData.subject.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("teach_class", detailsData.teach_class);
  formData.append("home_tuition", detailsData.home_tuition);
  formData.append("fees", detailsData.fees);
  formData.append("home_tuition_fees", detailsData.home_tuition_fees);
  formData.append("shift", detailsData.shift.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("board", detailsData.board.toUpperCase());
  formData.append("profile_photo", photo.image); // this is the image field 

  try {
    let response = await axiosInstance.put(`/teacher/edit-detail/`, formData);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      ToastNotification(
        "We are facing some problems. Please try again later",
        "error"
      );
      return error.response;
    } else {
      return error.request;
    }
  }
};
```

if no image is uploaded the by the user this is what is passed in **formData.append("profile_photo", photo.image);**

```
/media/photos/2022/05/12/jgs.jpeg
```

**TeacherDetail Model (Update)**

```
class TeacherDetail(models.Model):
    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    
    adhaar_number = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, null=True, blank=True)
    
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    
    age = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    name_of_school = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    
    experience = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    teach_for_no_days = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    shift = models.CharField(max_length=20 ,null=True, blank=True)
    
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    
    teach_class = models.CharField(max_length=100 ,null=True, blank=True)
    
    board = models.CharField(max_length=25,null=True, blank=True)
    
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=8 ,null=True, blank=True)
    
    fees = models.IntegerField( null=True, blank=True)
    
    fac = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    home_tuition = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    home_tuition_fees = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    hfac = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, editable= False)
```

Comment: Show me your TeacherDetail model

Comment: You need define the image in the form.

Comment: @LordPokerFace I have added the model

Answer (score 0):

You can take the form directly:

```
def edit_teacher_detail(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
    form = YourForm(request.POST)
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
        # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
```

PD: I think you can pass a form using PUT

Comment: The profile_photo comes  from a different state and in not under the **detaislData**. I do not face this error if the user uploads the photo. It only throws an error when the user does not upload a photo and the profile_photo does not come back as file

Comment: In forms.py in your django project you need a teacherdetailForm.

Comment: There is no forms.py sir. The data is coming from the React frontend.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/ read this topic.

Comment: You need catch the form sended by (frontend) in your backend app.

Comment: I understand all of this sir, I think my question is not clear to you

Comment: The problem is get a error when the image is empty.

Comment: I trying to say, the serializer is giving that error?

Comment: Yes the serializer is giving that error

Comment: I suggest change the serializer by a form object defined by you and the fields you want validate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144230/how-to-set-image-field-as-optional example

Comment: Thank you for trying but I figured out way to control it from the frontend

Comment: Please check my ans once

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to control sending of

```
formData.append("profile_photo", photo.image);
```

from the frontend itself.

What I did in the react is check whether the **typeof photo.image** is string or not. If it is a string this means that no file has been uploaded and it contains the url path, therefore, I do not append it in the formData else I append it. Below is my code

**react part**

```
if (typeof photo.image === "string") {
  } else {
    formData.append("profile_photo", photo.image);
  }
```

I do not know if this is an efficient way to do it. But for the time being this works for me. Please suggest if anyone has a better way to handle it in the backend.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940308/how-to-make-filefield-in-django-optional

Comment: I telling you the answer, define a form object with the fields you want validate or not and delete the serializer.